# Is there a shorter proof of Fermat's Last Theorem for $n=4$ than that of infinite descent?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Out of curiosity, i'm wondering whether there exists a shorter proof of FLT for $n=4$ with respect to the one of infinite descent ?
The Wikipedia article on this subject states that more proofs were later found by Euler, Hilbert and others, but none of these papers shows up after a Google search.

Comment: If google can't find them, they do not exist,

Comment: I guess Franz Lemmermeyer was being facetious, but I also guess you didn't try *very* hard, because in fact the Wikipedia article cites the articles by Euler and Hilbert in the reference section, and a translation of Euler's article (into German) can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3808v1.pdf.

Answer (score 7):

How much shorter than [one page](http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.co.uk/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-4.html) do you expect?

Comment: Just mere curiosity Igor, maybe one that can ''fit in the margin of the Arithmetica''.